# The minted not working with bash code

Tags: minted

I don't know why my MWE is not work for some keywords

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[outputdir=output]{minted}
\usepackage[skins,minted]{tcolorbox}


\newtcblisting{bashcode}[1][]{
    listing engine=minted,
    colframe=black!70,
    listing only,
    minted style=colorful, % pygmentize -L styles
    minted language=bash,
    minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
    left=5mm,enhanced,
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[red!20!blue!20!white] (frame.south west)
       rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{bashcode}[]
# test
cd ~/temp
mkdir latex-tests
cd latex-tests
mkdir output # For LaTeX compilation output
\end{bashcode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is because `minted` (or more precisely, Pygments) doesn't support those keywords. If you use `minted` environment, the minted output will be the same, so `tcolorbox` is "innocent" here.